# Forcing jqGrid to use JSON for create/delete/update

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm starting to use **jqGrid** to display/add/edit/delete some data that is coming from a REST service using JSON. Reading data works fine, however the other operations such as add,delete they cause a server error because I'm doing a POST of parameters using a Query String but the server is expecting JSON content:

```
$(document)
.ready(
        function() {
            $("#list")
                    .jqGrid(
                            {
                                url : 'http://localhost:8888/rest/service',
                                datatype : 'json',
                                mtype : 'GET',
                                colNames : [ 'name', 'city',
                                        'country'],
                                colModel : [ {
                                    name : 'name',
                                    index : 'name',
                                    width : 150,
                                    editable : true
                                }, {
                                    name : 'city',
                                    index : 'city',
                                    width : 150,
                                    editable : true
                                }, {
                                    name : 'country',
                                    index : 'country',
                                    width : 200,
                                    editable : true
                                } ],
                                pager : '#pager',
                                rowNum : 10,
                                rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                                sortname : 'invid',
                                sortorder : 'desc',
                                viewrecords : true,
                                gridview : true,
                                caption : 'Data Report',
                                jsonReader : {
                                    repeatitems : false,
                                },
                                editurl : "http://localhost:8888/rest/service/operate",
                                datatype : 'json'
                            });
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                edit : false,
                add : true,
                del : true,
                search : true
            });
        });
```

In another thread I've found the suggestion to use the following function to force JSON content for all operations but I've checked it just works for the "add" operation- it does not work if you attempt to edit/delete a row from the grid (Still sending a Query String instead of JSON content)

```
jQuery.extend(
        jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            recreateForm: true,
            serializeEditData: function(postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                return [true, "", res.d];
            }
        }
    );
```

Is there an easier way to fix the issue within my grid definition ?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I've updated the code as suggested by @lucasdc however now the error is "No URL is set". It seems like the URLs that I have indicated have not been included in my grid. Here follows the code:

```
$(document)
.ready(
        function() {
            $("#list")
                    .jqGrid(
                            {
                                url : 'http://localhost:8888/rest/service',
                                datatype : 'json',
                                mtype : 'GET',
                                colNames : [ 'name', 'surname',
                                        'address'],
                                colModel : [ {
                                    name : 'name',
                                    index : 'name',
                                    width : 150,
                                    editable : true
                                }, {
                                    name : 'surname',
                                    index : 'surname',
                                    width : 150,
                                    editable : true
                                }, {
                                    name : 'address',
                                    index : 'address',
                                    width : 200,
                                    editable : true
                                } ],
                                pager : '#pager',
                                rowNum : 10,
                                rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                                sortname : 'invid',
                                sortorder : 'desc',
                                viewrecords : true,
                                gridview : true,
                                caption : 'Data Report',
                                jsonReader : {
                                    repeatitems : false,
                                } 

                            });


            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                edit : true,
                add : true,
                del : true,
                search : true
            });


     $("#list").jqGrid(


     //edit options
{
    url:"http://localhost:8888/rest/service/operate",
    closeAfterEdit:true,
    reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
    onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        return [true, "", res.d];   
    }
},
//add options
{
    url:"http://localhost:8888/rest/service/operate",
    closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
    onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        return [true, "", res.d];       
    }
},
//del options
{
    url:'http://localhost:8888/rest/service/operate',
    onclickSubmit: function(url, postdata){
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        return [true, "", res.d];       
    }
},
{}, //search options
{} //refresh options




 );         

        });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list">
        <tr>
            <td />
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: u set datatype:'json' for two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it straight, you want to send JSON data on edit/add/delete operations in a grid. If that's your goal, you can make do it on `onclickSubmit` for each of the operations. First of all, you'll have to enable these operations:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:false}, // enable
// Now we set the options for each of the operations:
// Edit options
{
    url:"YOUR_EDIT_URL",
    closeAfterEdit:true,
    reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
    onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        return [true, "", res.d];   
    }
},
// Add options
{
    url:"YOUR_ADD_URL",
    closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
    onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        return [true, "", res.d];       
    }
},
// Del options
{
    url:'YOUR_DEL_URL',
    onclickSubmit: function(url, postdata){
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        return [true, "", res.d];       
    }
},
{}, // Search options
{}  // Refresh options
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've added at the bottom your options like this:
`$("#list").jqGrid({   
    url:'http://localhost:8888/rest/service',
    closeAfterEdit:true,
    reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
    onclickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {         
        return {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        }
    },
    afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        return [true, "", res.d];   
    }
},..`

But from the JS console I can see a Syntax error (Unexpected identifier)on:
**return JSON.stringify(postData);**

Comment: Thanks, however no I get a "No URL is set". I've updated the original question to show the full code. Thanks

Comment: The code to set options must be inside `$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', ...`. I've edited my answer again, take a look at it @user2824073